# How do I reset the chmod of the files from my working copy in Git command or Eclipse Git (EGit) plugin to the HEAD revision?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I don't know how that happened, but all of sudden a dozen of files from my local working copy appeared in the Git staging area under "Unstaged Changes". When I double-click to check the differences on each file, I see no differences.
When I try right-click => "Replace with HEAD revison", it has no effect (the files remain there in "Unstaged Changes"). Same thing if I do a Team->Reset to the latest HEAD revision.
When I do a `git diff` command, I can see the differences in file mode :

- old mode 100755
- new mode 100644

I tried to switch all these files back from 100644 to 100755 by adding them the +x.
However, doing `git update-index --chmod=+x /path/to/file` or `git add --chmod=+x /path/to/file` didn't help.
I do not want to commit any change on the file mode, how do I reset their mode so they're in sync with the HEAD ?
Plus, I have no change to commit on these files.
Also, any idea how I could have ended up in that situation, knowing it's a Windows-only project ?

Comment: Answering only for the *Git* side of things, Git believes the file system's modes if `core.fileMode` is `true` and disbelieves them if `core.fileMode` is `false`. You should not normally change this yourself (and should never *have to* change it) but if it's wrong for your file system, you *can* change it. Eclipse uses egit, which may or may not use some other setting; I can't speak for those.

Comment: I've set core.fileMode to false in the Windows->Preferences, under Git->Configuration and selected all files, and right-clicked "Replace with HEAD revison" and now it's ok.